# JavaScript libraries for rich interactions

Tags: javascript

If I am developing a highly interactive website that can be accessed from both desktops and mobile devices, what are the recommended JavaScript libraries?

Comment: theres probably 20 or more of them. Most are good. Pick one of the popular ones and run. if it doesn't work, try another.

Answer (score 0):

My personal favourite is `jQuery`

Worth a read 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-js-separate-library-or-is-the-mobile-support-being-pushed-into-core